# Using stream collect to return the same list cutting and summing the duplicates, throwing a non-static reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

So, i'm trying to Return a list of a list, but cutting and summing the duplicates, like that.

```
ID 1, VALUE 5
ID 1, VALUE 6
ID 2, VALUE 5
ID 3, VALUE 8
ID 3, VALUE 9
```

Return

```
ID 1, VALUE 11
ID 2, VALUE 5 
ID 3, VALUE 17
```

And I searched here in StackOverflow and achieve this,

```
list.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(ListDTO::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(ListDTO::getValue)));
```

So, for this to return a list, a did that,

```
list = list.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(ListDTO::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(ListDTO::getValue), Collectors.toList()));
```

But, it's now giving me this error

```
Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Here in specific

```
ListDTO::getId
```

So, anyone can explain me te problem? or have a better aproach to this?

My ListDTO

```java
@Getter
@Setter

public class ListDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Double value;

    private Long id;

    public ListDTO(){}

    public ListDTO(Double value, Long id){
        this.value = value;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case, you wanted to continue where you left off, `List<ListDTO> result = list.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(ListDTO::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(ListDTO::getValue))).entrySet().stream().map(e -> new  ListDTO(e.getValue(), e.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Naman this worked fine, but, u can explain me how this work? You Mapped the result into a new object and returned it? I'm new to java 8 streams concept, you will help me a lot, well, thank you very much for your help

Comment: I `stream`ed the data twice. Once for what you were summing the values into a `Map<Long, Double>` and then from this map iterating through the entry set and using the key-value pairs for creating the objects back and collecting them back to list.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. you can use `toMap` collector with merge function.

```
 Map<Integer,ListDTO> mapById = list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(ListDTO::getId,
                       Function.identity(),(l1,l2)->{l1.sumValue(l2);return l1;}));
```

then

```
List<ListDTO> result = new ArrayList<>(mapById.values());
```

you should declare a method

```
public ListDTO sumValue(ListDTO l){
     this.value += l.value;
     return this;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create new object?

Comment: I will use it with another list with the same id but different properties with the respective ids to create a new list, based on some properties from these two lists

Comment: @OLendari0 The solution here is better than the comment by me or your approach as it would stream the data only once and ensure that you get the result as values of the `Map` itself since the type to `collect` is same as that of input, here shouldn't be any need to `map` the data as I did in my comment.

Comment: @Naman no, the solution of your comment is better, as it doesn’t make spurious modifications to the original objects.